# getting the difference of two dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the difference of months between two dates that are in two separate columns in my dataframe. I've looked at multiple examples here in stackoverflow but when I implement these methods, I get negative numbers. Below is an example of my df and the code that I'm using.

```
 issued_date    final_date     months       delta
  29/05/2017     31/05/2020     36              36.6
  25/02/2019     31/05/2020     15          15.36666667
  04/07/2020     31/05/2020     -1         -1.133333333
  03/09/2020     31/05/2020     -3         -3.166666667
  06/07/2019     31/05/2020     10              11
  25/01/2018     31/05/2020     28         28.56666667
```

The data types for issued_date and final_date are they same:

```
datetime64[ns]
```

I have tried to different versions below you can find each

```
 df['delta'] = df['final_date'] - df['issued_date']
 df['delta'] = df['delta'].dt.days/30

 df['months'] = df['final_date'].sub(df['issued_date'],                                                                                                                           
 axis=0)
 df['months'] = df['months'] /  np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
 df['months'] = df['months'].astype(int)
```

I can't figure out why it's calculating the number of months wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The number of months is correct. You have some issue dates that are after the final dates.

Comment: I think problem is precisely that the dates have been converted differently in each row

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is precisely that the dates have been converted differently in each row. Hence making the calculations correct. I need to identify how each one of them are different